# Notepad in c# Replace All

Tags: c#, notepad

I have made replace function, but I am really struggling to make "Replace All"
function. 
I tried to make into for loop but that didn't work well...
I have dialog box just like in usual Notepad (another form) and i have richtextbox in Main form. Any ideas how can I make it?

Comment: Could you edit your question to share some of your code? It's super hard to help without seeing your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the String.Replace method:

```
private void DoReplace(string SearchFor, string ReplaceWith)
{
    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(SearchFor, ReplaceWith);
}
```

Call this function and supply the string you want to search for in `Richtextbox1` (or whatever it is called in your case) as the first parameter and the replacement as the second parameter.